# Use flatMap or zip in RxJava2?

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

I have a class called `Student` and it has two fields `grade` and `school`. Both of two fields need to be fetched from remote server. When two result returned, I new a `Student` object.

With help of `RxJava`, I have done it in two ways, one in `flatMap` and another in `zip` operator.

```
Observable<String> gradeObservable =
        Observable.create((ObservableOnSubscribe<String>) emitter -> {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            emitter.onNext("senior");
        }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());

Observable<String> schoolObservable =
        Observable.create((ObservableOnSubscribe<String>) emitter -> {
            emitter.onNext("MIT");
        }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
```

## flatMap version

```
gradeObservable
        .flatMap(grade ->
                schoolObservable.map(school -> {
                    Student student = new Student();
                    student.grade = grade;
                    student.school = school;
                    return student;
                }))
        .subscribe(student -> {
            System.out.println(student.grade);
            System.out.println(student.school);
        });
```

## zip version

```
 Observable.zip(gradeObservable, schoolObservable, (grade, school) -> {
    Student student = new Student();
    student.grade = grade;
    student.school = school;
    return student;
}).subscribe(student -> {
    System.out.println(student.grade);
    System.out.println(student.school);
});
```

In my opinion, `zip` seems more clearly. So **in this situation, operator `flatMap` or `zip` is better**?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are clearly composing two observable, which is the purpose of [`zip()`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html). Not only that but `gradeObservable` and `schoolObservable` would be executed in parallel with `zip()` whereas your `flatmap()` solution would serialize requests. So, yes, `zip()` is better.