# What are the connections and differences between Observables in JavaFX and RxJava

Tags: java, javafx, observable, rx-java, frp

Generally, an observable is something whose changes can be observed.

In JavaFX, [an `Observable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/Observable.html) is used to represent a state of UI. With its subclass `Property` we can manually `getValue` and `setValue` and then its value and other subscribed values are updated accordingly.

I am new to RxJava. However from what I have learned, [an `Observable`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html) is more like a lazy list whose elements are generated when needed, but how they are generated is determined when creating the `Observable` and it's not subject to later change.

What are the connections and differences between the two? Is it possible to replace one with the other?

And understanding them in 2 different ways also makes the definitions of some functional transformations ambiguous. For example, when combining observables we might use `bind`/`flatMap` or `zip`. (also see [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49177746/use-flatmap-or-zip-in-rxjava2)) For a state, in the sense of functional reactive programming, the result represents the current combined and then transformed state, which just depends on the current state of its 2 dependencies. For a lazy list, `flatMap` creates the cartesian product of 2 lists and transforms them, and `zip` pairs 2 lists by order instead of by current state or time.

Comment: (Not sure, so just a comment) I think the JavaFX `Observable` is not very related to the React one, mostly because the later one is the core conept of its reactive programming paradigm. The JavaFX one is only similar in that it also deals with observable events, but is much more concerned about values (properties) changing values over time and other values being recalculated/adjusted based on that. The reactive approach doesn't necessarily imply a changing value over time, it can very easily just represent a longrunning process that eventually returns one value.

Comment: Another major difference is that RxJava is designed to be multi-threaded from the ground up. The JavaFX observables are all single-threaded; they don't _have_ to be, but all the core implementations are. That's because JavaFX's observables are meant to help with UI binding which all happens on a single thread anyway (the _JavaFX Application Thread_).